# Navigation Bar Creation Error

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I tried to finalize the code for the navigation bar it gives me this error which is the R which I tried fixing but it doesn't work at all.

The Code for the Navigation Bar as image:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n33Y8.png]

and as code sample:

```
public class NavigationBar extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static final android.R.
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(nToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(nToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private void setContentView() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(nToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your code and the error you are getting so that it will be better to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is three possible fix for this.

1. Add the `import yourPackageName.R;`
2. Menu Build>Rebuild Project
3. Menu File>Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Try  Opening File->Settings, then Editor->General->Auto Import, then Enable Optimize imports on the the Fly, and Add unambiguous imports on the fly.
If there some error in your import thi might solve it.

Comment: I couldn't find what you told me to at all.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in top of your activity

```
import package_name.R;
```

Find package name in **Manifest file** and after that again Build your project

Comment: can u add the screenshot of ypur package name(Manifest file) and also try to add the screenshot where u add `import package_name.R;` these lines

Comment: Please find attached photo.

Answer (score 0):

U need fix like below

```
//remove
private static final android.R;

//add this to your imports on top
import your_app_package.R;
```

R is system generate class which contains unique hex-code for app level resource Id's.
Since R is class, you need to import that Class if you want to use that class members.

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Android Studio.

Comment: clean build, then rebuild.

Comment: Same Problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="team19.uni2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="and`a`roid.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AlternativeGeolocation" />
        <activity android:name=".HomePage" />
        <activity android:name=".WelcomePage" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfilePage" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Config" />
        <activity android:name=".Help" />
        <activity android:name=".StartUpPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NavigationBar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigationbar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```